# Problem pickling parameters of a function including datetime with python pickle module

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, pickle

I'm working with python3 and trying to cache some functions with the filecache module.
I'm encountering problem with some datetime
I've minified the problem in the following sample:

```
import pickle
import datetime
testDate = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
arguments = (1, 2, testDate)
arguments_pickle = pickle.dumps(arguments, protocol=0).decode('ascii')
```

which produce the error
...
  File "C:/wamp64/www/givingsense.eu/datamusee/python/datamusee/trials/testProblemPickle.py", line 5, in 
    arguments_pickle = pickle.dumps(arguments, protocol=0).decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdf in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)

I'm stuck with that.
Advices? Help?
Thank you in advance

Comment: The error tells you that you have bytes in `arguments_pickle` which do not have character representations in the ASCII protocol (hexadecimal DF is decimal 223). The question you should ask yourself is: does it make sense in the first place to decode the bytes to characters?

Answer (score 0):

What do you plan to do with `arguments_pickle`?

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) state that `pickle.dumps()` returns *the pickled representation of the object obj as a `bytes` object*. And it is by no means a valid ascii string, so it's not surprising that you receive an error when you call `.decode('ascii')`.

Try this instead:

```py
arguments_pickle = pickle.dumps(arguments, protocol=0)
```

**EDIT:**

There is a bug in the `filecache` module. It hasn't been updated in 5 years. There are 2 open pull requests just sitting there. It seems the author is not interested in maintaining this module.

You need to change line 119 of `\lib\site-packages\filecache\__init__.py` from this:

```py
        arguments_pickle = _pickle.dumps(arguments, protocol=0).decode('ascii')
```

to this:

```py
        arguments_pickle = str(_pickle.dumps(arguments))
```

Comment: I'm using the filecache module which have such code  and was correctly working until I'm trying to try to 'filecache' functions with a datetime parameter. The inner code of filecache is <code>
        arguments_pickle = _pickle.dumps(arguments, protocol=0).decode('ascii')
</code>

Comment: See my updated answer. There is a bug in `filecache`.